# iOS - Double tap on uibutton

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, button, gesture

I have a button and I'm testing the taps on it, with one tap it change a background color, with two taps another color and with three taps another color again.
The code is:

```
- (IBAction) button 
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapOnce = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapOnce:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapTwice = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapTwice:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapTrice = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapTrice:)];

    tapOnce.numberOfTapsRequired  = 1;
    tapTwice.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    tapTrice.numberOfTapsRequired = 3;

    //stops tapOnce from overriding tapTwice
    [tapOnce requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapTwice];
    [tapTwice requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapTrice];

    //then need to add the gesture recogniser to a view - this will be the view that recognises the gesture
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapOnce];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapTwice];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapTrice];
}

- (void)tapOnce:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{ 
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
}

- (void)tapTwice:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}

- (void)tapTrice:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; 
}
```

The problem is that the first tap don't works, the other yes.
If I use this code without button it works perfectly.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you adding this gestures on button tap? why dont you add it in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Because I must use this gesture only on a small part of view.

Comment: But your code is setting gestures on the whole `self.view`. You should change it as shown in my answer then.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want the colors to change on tap of button, you should add these gestures on button in `viewDidLoad` method or so rather than on the same button action. The above code will repeatedly add gestures on tap of the button to the `self.view` and not on `button`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      UITapGestureRecognizer *tapOnce = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapOnce:)];
      UITapGestureRecognizer *tapTwice = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapTwice:)];
      UITapGestureRecognizer *tapTrice = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapTrice:)];

      tapOnce.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
      tapTwice.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
      tapTrice.numberOfTapsRequired = 3;
      //stops tapOnce from overriding tapTwice
      [tapOnce requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapTwice];
      [tapTwice requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapTrice];

      //then need to add the gesture recogniser to a view - this will be the view that recognises the gesture
      [self.button addGestureRecognizer:tapOnce]; //remove the other button action which calls method `button`
      [self.button addGestureRecognizer:tapTwice];
      [self.button addGestureRecognizer:tapTrice];
}
```