# Identify the cell that was clicked - Beginner

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an UITableView. There are 5 rows and 4 buttons each in a row. When the user taps the button i want to retrieve the row ID.

I have used `UITapGestureRecognizer` to recognise the Button that was selected. Now i want to find the Row the button is.

I wanted to use cell.myButton.tag =indexRow.row;. However, i am not able to receive it from `ImageTapped` method. Can someone help me out ?

Following code is part of  `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = nil;

            tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ImageTapped:)];

            [cell.myButton addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

... Like wise for the other button as well.

**ImageTapped** method

```
- (void) ImageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: @iphonic : **TapGesture don't work with UIButtons**, who told you that?

Comment: @iphonic : ***I tried & used TapGesture for finding double  taps on UIButton.*** [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750014/ios-double-tap-on-uibutton)

Comment: @FahimParkar Applogies Sir, it does work, I was in different thoughts, thanks for clarification..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all why are you using gesture and there no need to add gesture. You can do this thing by using `addTarget` Method.

In this method  `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
myButton.tag = indexPath.row;
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ImageTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and you can get in this method:

```
- (void) ImageTapped:(id) sender {
    int rowId = [(UIButton *)sender tag];
}
```

Other wise you can get like this:

```
cell.myButton.tag = indexPath.row;// In cellForRowAtIndexPath Method

- (void) ImageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {

    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        int rowId = recognizer.view.tag;  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the button will be cell's descendent child. so you can get cell with the follow code:

```
id view;
while (![(view = button.superView)  isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) ;
// now view will be the parent cell.
```

Comment: ... and then you use indexPathOfCell to get the index path of the cell. Which is much better than getting a tag, because it will give you the indexPath even if rows have been rearranged, so this is a solution that scales.