# UITapGestureRecognizer with exact number of taps

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I would like to respond to multiple taps on a `UIView`. For example, I should be able to tap the view five times for one action, and ten times for another action. But - each action should not be triggered by any number of taps other than it's prescribed count. I.e. the five-tap action should not fire after six taps or ten taps, and the ten-tap action should not fire after eleven taps.

Is this possible with a `UITapGestureRecognizer`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible,

but you must measure out the `numberOfTapsRequired` and `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` usage.

You can discard the taps that you won't use and trigger what you want in the method only on the number of taps that you want.

You can see an example of the usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750014/ios-double-tap-on-uibutton).

Comment: Do you mean I should add a gesture recognizer for every integer between five and ten, and require my actual gestures to fail for each one? What about 11+?