# Change backgroundColor of button when tapped with Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, swift4

I'm trying to change the `backgroundColor` for a button on tap. When the button is tapped, it should change the `backgroundColor`. But my problem is that I need two taps for this event. And I don't understand why.

My code:

```swift
for (index, cue) in cuestionesCC.enumerated(){
    let buttonYes = UIButton()
    buttonYes.backgroundColor = .green
    buttonYes.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -10, left: -10, bottom: -10, right: -10) // Add padding around text
    buttonYes.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
    buttonYes.tag = 1
    buttonYes.setTitle("Yes", for: .normal)
    buttonYes.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonActionYesNo), for: .touchUpInside)

    let buttonNo = UIButton()
    buttonNo.backgroundColor = .red
    buttonNo.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -10, left: -10, bottom: -10, right: -10) // Add padding around text
    buttonNo.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
    buttonNo.tag = 2
    buttonNo.setTitle("No", for: .normal)
    buttonNo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonActionYesNo), for: .touchUpInside)

    stackViewH.addArrangedSubview(buttonYes)
    stackViewH.addArrangedSubview(buttonNo)
}

@objc func buttonActionYesNo(sender: UIButton!) {
    print (sender.tag)
    sender.backgroundColor = .gray
}
```

When I tap the button once, it prints the tag. But I need another tap additional for change the `backgroundColor` of the button. I don't understand that logic.

Comment: The problem might be that you don't get a redraw because the button is busy animating the tap. Try adding a `delay` around `sender.backgroundColor = .gray`. Start with a big delay, like 1 second, and see if that helps. If it does, try shorter delays.

Comment: Maybe try for .touchDown rather than for .touchUpInside and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Yes, I tried .touchDown, .touchOutInside, ... all events... but nothing happens. The strange thing is that it does read the print at the first touch, but the color change only at the second touch.

Comment: I've also tried the delay in a new thread, but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the background color of a UIButton while it's highlighted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523348/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-uibutton-while-its-highlighted)

Comment: I have reviewed that thread, but it is not relevant to my question.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the same. Do you have your code hosted somewhere? Github may be?

Comment: What is `cuestionesCC`? Maybe your button gets overwritten by a new one in the for loop after you tap and therefore you don't see the color change.

Comment: cuestionesCC is a Array. Its value is dynamic and may vary. Sometimes it has 5 elements, other 10, other 8... the program goes through that array and creates as many pairs of YES / NO buttons as the array indicates. This works well. Create a list with several questions and each question two buttons: Yes and No.

Comment: Did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750014/ios-double-tap-on-uibutton ?

Comment: Yes, i saw and tried to did it with UITapGestureRecognizer, but don't work. (i hate swift and its ilogic logic)